# Reading Freebase data dump in python, read to few lines?

Tags: python, file, readline, freebase

I am trying to use the freebase data dump, but it seams that I have some problems reading the files with python. It looks like that my program cant read all the lines.

```
def test2():
    count=0
    for line in open(FREEBASE_TOPIC):
        count+=1
    return count

def test3():
    count=0
    for line in open(FREEBASE_QUAD):
        count+=1
    return count


if __name__ == "__main__":

   print "FREEBASE TOPIC - NR LINES:",test2()
   print "FREEBASE QUAD - NR LINES:",test3()
```

Results in this:

```
FREEBASE TOPIC - ITR TIME: 1.21000003815
FREEBASE TOPIC - NR LINES: 1643010

FREEBASE QUAD - ITER TIME: 0.797000169754
FREEBASE QUAD - NR LINES: 3155131
```

This can be all. It looks to be to few lines to contain the whole freebase. And I cant see how it is possible to iterate over one 33GB file and another 5GB file in 2 seconds.

What is wrong? I am downloading the files again in case something went wrong during the download process, but it takes decades with my connections, so I am asking ere in the mean time. The file size is correct, and i have printed some of the lines and they look correct.

Comment: what does ``wc -l yourfile`` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a problem that occurred to me:

```
open('file', 'rb')
```

should solve it.

```
chr(26)
```

sometimes causes an file ending for text mode 'r' that is default.

Comment: open('file', 'rb') instead of open('file') worked!  codecs.open('file',"r","utf-8") also works, but it produces more lines than there is because some of the Unicode characters from it signals a new line, Which is bad in tsv files.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are decompressing the files before using them.  You're almost certainly better off keeping the file compressed and decompressing it as you access it.

```
from bz2 import BZ2File
for line in BZ2File('freebase-datadump-quadruples-<date>.tsv.bz2','rU'):
    <process a line>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script runs fine and produces the correct numbers of lines for me on Ubuntu. Could this be a limitation of your OS?

[Parsing large (20GB) text file with python - reading in 2 lines as 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220862/parsing-large-20gb-text-file-with-python-reading-in-2-lines-as-1)